# Hook video stream in Windows (how to?)

Tags: c++, video, directx, hook, directx-11

My target is to hook video-stream **before it will going to video cards memory**. For example I'm using vlc-player (or another), so I need to hook frame and modify it before it will be placed to video memory.
How can i solve it (may be i need to hook some WinAPI, possible DirectX)?
How most popular players do rendering? What libraries it using? DirectX?
Finally how video (mpeg4) rendering works in Windows? My be you have some links, manuals?

For some reason I can't use DirectShow filters :(

Comment: This question is way too broad, you need to ask a specific question about a problem you are facing.

Comment: You can't do that. There's no single standard api for accessing videofiles, so you can't hook the stream in general case. Windows has DirectShow, but the player can ignore directshow and decode the stream by itself, without communicating with OS.

Comment: Ok. Im understand. So the question is that may be the last point before row (decoded) data will come to video memory? How video rendering works in windows?

Comment: There's no "last point" that is used in all players. There are *many* different ways to put data onto screen (at least: DirectX, OpenGL, DirectDraw, GDI, probably others) they are configurable (software/hardware surface, etc), and you don't really know which one of them is being used.

Comment: :( ok. So as you understand, i need to develop protection engine for video (for 5d cinema). I found interesting thing. All cinemas using NVIDIA 3D Vision it hooks directx and makes sterio effect. So my target is to hook 3D Vision and modify my video before it will transfered to video card by directx =)